# Problem setting base sdk to 4.0 and OS Deployment Target to 3.1.3 (Using MapKit)

Tags: iphone, deployment, operating-system, mapkit, target

I'm building an application that uses MapKit functionality. The base sdk is 4.0 but I'm building to a 3.1.3 device (the OS Deployment Target is set to 3.1.3). After the app is installed and right when it begins to run, I run into the following error:

dyld: Symbol not found: _CLLocationCoordinate2DMake Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.) mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack. mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack. kill quit

Keep in mind that this crash happens before the user would do anything at all. I have correctly added the MapKit Library and it builds and runs fine on a 4.0 device.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you make sure to link both MapKit and CoreLocation?

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling CLLocationCoordinate2DMake anywhere in your code? If so, this is probably the problem. You should make sure to not call this method when it's not present (check to see if CLLocationCoordinate2DMake != nil before calling).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationFunctions/Reference/reference.html) it is only available in iOS4.0 and later